# What is the Zhang's rule?

Tags: association-rules, market-basket-analysis

I'd been doing some reading on Association Rule Mining and bumped into a Kaggle dataset where a competitor had applied Zhang's rule. I would like to know what it is. I tried to look for it online, and most of the hits revolve around some Chinese emperor by that name whol ruled China. And the other things arn't really relevant. If there is anything that you can share about it, like its significance that'd be great.

There's also no tag that even starts with "Zha" in here.

Answer (score 0):

That could be a reference to the book "Association Rule Mining: Models and Algorithms" by Chengqi Zhang and Shichao Zhang which includes mining quantitative association rules, causal rules, exceptional rules, negative association rules, association rules in multi-databases, and association rules in small databases.

Comment: Thanks. I did come across this also when I was looking around, but here's the thing: It is a parameter that is passed to `mlxtend.frequent_patterns.association_rules.assign` (in the notebook code). There's nothing about anything beyond `association_rules` in its own official documentation. Here's the URL for the notebook: https://www.kaggle.com/code/foolwuilin/market-basket-analysis-with-apriori?scriptVersionId=70840054&cellId=13. Here's the documentation for `association_rules` https://rasbt.github.io/mlxtend/api_subpackages/mlxtend.frequent_patterns/#association_rules